# Asynchronous NSURLConnection call

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am making a Asynchronous NSURLConnection call and downloading the data, how can I know when this thread is completed?

I am making this call from viewDidLoad, and obviously NSURLConnection is intuitively running in separate thread. So how would I know if the thread is completed and second wait until the thread gets completed to get the data pulled to the viewcontroller.

Comment: Have you even thought of searching for it?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to assign a delegate to the NSURLConnection that handles the processing and what-not of the data. Check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE), it's pretty straightforward!

Answer (score 0):

code speaks for itself

```
-(void) startRequest {
    NSURLRequest* req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];    
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [connection release];
}
```